# Match exact string ignoring special characters like hyphen

Tags: linux, grep

I have a text file like

```
Data1 AppFlows
Data2 AppFlows-1
```

If I do

```
grep '\bAppFlows\b' file
```

It prints both the lines, which means we don't seem to consider `-` in the boundary

I looked around and found something like

```
grep -w 'AppFlows$' file
```

But this did not help.

Any way to print the line with exact character match and the output be like

```
Data1 AppFlows
```

Comment: So should that second line be matched if the search term is `AppFlows1`, or what do you mean with "ignoring special characters"?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `-w` means "select  only  those  lines  containing  matches that form whole words". In your case, the `-` is indeed taken as a word boundary, which means that `AppFlows-1` contains `AppFlows` as a "whole word" just like `AppFlows foo` does. Now, your approach with `$` failed because you have whitespace after `AppFlows`, so you can try this with GNU `grep` instead:

```
$ grep -wP 'AppFlows\w*$' file
Data1 AppFlows
```

That will match `AppFlows` followed by 0 or more whitespace characters until the end of the line when this appears as a whole word.

Another approach would be to look for lines whose second field is exactly `AppFlows`:

```
$ awk '$2=="AppFlows"' file
Data1 AppFlows
```

Or, if you don't know in advance which field it will be, use:

```
$ awk '{ k=0;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i=="AppFlows"){k++}}}k' file
Data1 AppFlows
```

Comment: I wonder if perl lookarounds might be useful here as well ex. `AppFlows(?!-)` (which seems close in intent to the OP's `AppFlows\b`)

Comment: @steeldriver it would have to be something like `grep -P '(?<=[^a-zA-Z])AppFlows(?![^a-zA-Z])'` though, to avoid matching `fooApplflows` or `AppFlows!` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like

```
 egrep "(^|[^-])\AppFlows\b([^-]|$)"
```

For anyone who stumbles on this

Comment: You probably meant `grep -E "(^|[^-])AppFlows\b([^-]|$)"` but this won't do what you want. For example, it would match `zAppFlows` or anything else that ends in `AppFows` as long as it doesn't end in `-AppFlows`.